# Get element id by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html output :

```html
...
<ul id="commentlist">
    <li id="comment-12" data-post="post-1">Comment 1 for post 1</li>
    <li id="comment-34" data-post="post-1">Comment 2 for post 1</li>
    <li id="comment-56" data-post="post-1">Comment 3 for post 1</li>
</ul>
<ul id="commentlist">
    <li id="comment-78" data-post="post-2">Comment 1 for post 2</li>
    <li id="comment-90" data-post="post-2">Comment 2 for post 2</li>
</ul>
...
```

Please help me to generate 2 dementional array (like below) with jQuery:

```js
array = [
    "post-1": ["comment-12", "comment-34", "comment-56"],
    "post-2": ["comment-78", "comment-90"] 
]
```

I've tried:

```
jQuery("li[data-post]").each(function(){
    /*console.log(jQuery(this)); -- this contains necessary "id" but I don't know how to fetch it*/

    var testdata = jQuery(this).data('post');
    if (comment_lists.indexOf(testdata) == -1)
        comment_lists.push(testdata);
});
```

Comment: Well, did you mean *do it for me* instead of "help"? Please show what you've tried.

Comment: jQuery("li[data-post]").each(function(){
 //console.log(jQuery(this)); -- this contains necessary "id" but I don't know how to fetch it

 var testdata = jQuery(this).data('post');
 if (comment_lists.indexOf(testdata) == -1)
  comment_lists.push(testdata);

});

Comment: That's not an array. It's an object (with wrong sort of brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method to iterate over elements and generate object inside based on the data attribute.

```js
var obj = {};

// select elements with the attribute and iterate
$('[data-post]').each(function() {
  // get data attribute value
  var d = $(this).data('post');
  // define the property if not already defined
  obj[d] = obj[d] || [];
  // push the id of element
  obj[d].push(this.id)
})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="commentlist">
  <li id="comment-12" data-post="post-1">Comment 1 for post 1</li>
  <li id="comment-34" data-post="post-1">Comment 2 for post 1</li>
  <li id="comment-56" data-post="post-1">Comment 3 for post 1</li>
</ul>
<ul id="commentlist">
  <li id="comment-78" data-post="post-2">Comment 1 for post 2</li>
  <li id="comment-90" data-post="post-2">Comment 2 for post 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of array you can use **Object** to return data like this

```js
var obj = {};

$('ul').each(function() {
  var li = $(this).find('li');
  obj[li.data('post')] = li.map(function() {return $(this).attr('id') }).get();
})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="commentlist">
  <li id="comment-12" data-post="post-1">Comment 1 for post 1</li>
  <li id="comment-34" data-post="post-1">Comment 2 for post 1</li>
  <li id="comment-56" data-post="post-1">Comment 3 for post 1</li>
</ul>
<ul id="commentlist">
  <li id="comment-78" data-post="post-2">Comment 1 for post 2</li>
  <li id="comment-90" data-post="post-2">Comment 2 for post 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is iterating over all `[data-post]` elements and writing them to an object.

var array = {};

```
$('[data-post]').each(function(idx, el){
  var name = $(el).attr('data-post');
  if (!array.hasOwnProperty(name) {
    array[name] = [];
  }

  array[name].push($(el).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {};

$('ul li').each(function(){
    var post_name = $(this).data('post');

    if(!data[post_name])
        data[post_name] = [];

    data[post_name].push($(this).text());
});

console.log(data);
```